# ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError when form submission fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm creating a profile picture functionality in my rails app using `ActiveStorage` and I've been having issues with it for a long time now because when a form submission fails due to another field failing validation, I get the `ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError`.

When the error occurs, it is because of my `_picture.html.erb`:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "picture" do %>
  <%= image_tag profile.picture_thumbnail, class: "rounded-circle", size: "100x100", alt: "Profile pic" %>
<% end %>
```

```
#profile.rb
  def picture_thumbnail
    if picture.attached? && picture.representable?
      picture.representation(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]).processed
    else
      'default.png'
    end
  end
```

To bypass the error, I had to do this in my `profiles_controller.rb`:

```
  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    picture = params[:profile][:picture]
  
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params.except(:picture))

        # The file is only attached if it was uploaded successfully and exists as a blob.
        # This prevents the ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError from being raised when the form submission fails.
        if picture.present?
          @profile.picture.attach(picture)
        end

        format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:notice] = "Profile information have been updated" }
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@profile.user), notice: "Profile information have been updated" }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity, alert: "Error while updating profile" }
      end
    end
  end
```

But doing this causes any validations I make for the `picture` to be skipped because I'm excluding it with `(.except)` and updating it manually. It's the only way I've been able to figure out how to get around the error but the downside is that I can't get the validation for the picture to work with it.